# How do I change the language of Firefox 4?

Tags: language, firefox

I've just downloaded Firefox 4. I can't find an option to change the language (I would like to change it from Hebrew to English).

I'm talking about the language of the browser user interface. The UI is in Hebrew. I want the UI to be in English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to download the English version.  The version you have will be the Hebrew one.

http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all.html

Answer (score 5):

Download the [English version](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all.html). I don't think it's possible to change the language of an already installed browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a plugin with the right language. All languages for Windows are found [here](http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/4.0/win32/xpi/). Browse around for other platforms.

Also you can find installers there for every language separately.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the site http://kb.mozillazine.org/Change_Default_Mozilla_Language, download the proper language pack and install it as add-on. Success.
jrm

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox press the Alt button to bring up the menu bar. Then Tools -> options, click on the content tab (the thrid one along). Then languages click on choose.

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't talking about the language of the web pages, I was talking about the language of the browser user interface. It's in Hebrew and I would like it to be in English.